# Screen inside conda environment doesn't use python PATH

Tags: python, conda, gnu-screen

I have a conda environment that is running python 3.10.5. It works on the terminal without screen. First I did

```
conda deactivate
```

And `conda info` at this step shows:

```
     active environment : base
    active env location : /home/myuser/anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /home/myuser/.condarc
 populated config files : 
          conda version : 4.13.0
    conda-build version : 3.21.8
         python version : 3.9.12.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=10.2=0
                          __linux=5.4.0=0
                          __glibc=2.27=0
                          __unix=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : /home/myuser/anaconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /home/myuser/anaconda3/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /home/myuser/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /home/myuser/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/myuser/anaconda3/envs
                          /home/myuser/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.13.0 requests/2.27.1 CPython/3.9.12 Linux/5.4.0-109-generic ubuntu/18.04.6 glibc/2.27
                UID:GID : 1001272705:1000000513
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

then I did

```
screen -S scren_name
```

and the `conda info` at this step is

```
     active environment : base
    active env location : /home/myuser/anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /home/myuser/.condarc
 populated config files : 
          conda version : 4.13.0
    conda-build version : 3.21.8
         python version : 3.9.12.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=10.2=0
                          __linux=5.4.0=0
                          __glibc=2.27=0
                          __unix=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : /home/myuser/anaconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /home/myuser/anaconda3/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /home/myuser/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /home/myuser/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/myuser/anaconda3/envs
                          /home/myuser/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.13.0 requests/2.27.1 CPython/3.9.12 Linux/5.4.0-109-generic ubuntu/18.04.6 glibc/2.27
                UID:GID : 1001272705:1000000513
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

then I activated the environment in screen. Now `conda info` says

```
     active environment : catvehicle
    active env location : /home/myuser/anaconda3/envs/catvehicle
            shell level : 2
       user config file : /home/myuser/.condarc
 populated config files : 
          conda version : 4.13.0
    conda-build version : 3.21.8
         python version : 3.9.12.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=10.2=0
                          __linux=5.4.0=0
                          __glibc=2.27=0
                          __unix=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : /home/myuser/anaconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /home/myuser/anaconda3/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /home/myuser/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /home/myuser/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/myuser/anaconda3/envs
                          /home/myuser/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.13.0 requests/2.27.1 CPython/3.9.12 Linux/5.4.0-109-generic ubuntu/18.04.6 glibc/2.27
                UID:GID : 1001272705:1000000513
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

However, when I write `python` in screen, the version shown is the default Ubuntu 18.04 included python which is 2.7, and not the 3.10.5 version that was part of my conda env.

how can I fix this, or make it use the proper python?

Comment: Yeah, that's odd. I use screen all the time and have never encountered this. Do you have `shell -${SHELL}` in your `~/.screenrc` file? Might help to also see the `PATH` variable after the activations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: as mentioned by other users, setting an alias is not recommended. I was able to fix it by:

1. Entering screen
2. Writing `conda deactivate` until the `(base)` environment was no longer activated either.
3. Writing `conda activate my_env` to activate.

Now the `python` path is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot! After hours of searching other posts and messing around with my bash_profile and even reinstalling python, anaconda, and changing alias, this was the simple solution that worked!